# Using Gatling Expression Language in Flood.io

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to get my Gatling scala script running in Flood.io.
The script uses Gatling EL and works when I am running it locally with gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-3.7.4

```
doIf("#{jwtToken.isUndefined()}"){...
```

But when uploaded to Flood.io I get this error in their logs:

```
14:37:30.199 [ERROR] i.g.c.action.If - 'if-8' failed to execute: j.l.IllegalArgumentException: For input string: "#{jwtToken.isUndefined()}"
```

Thanks in advance

**[EDIT] Solution found**
When using the old EL syntax ($ instead of #) I got it running.
Furthermore, the Flood.io support needed to set my Gatling version to 3.2 on my Flood.io account.

```
doIf("${jwtToken.isUndefined()}"){...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: Gatling creator and CTO (meaning Flood.io is a competitor of ours)

This error means Flood.io doesn't support Gatling 3.7 as of now.